# get or create - unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: django

models:

```
class TestVersion(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views:

```
test = Test.objects.get(id=id)
result = TestVersion.objects.get_or_create(test=test)
result.count += 1
result.save()
```

I have this error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method' and
>   'int'

on line: `result.count += 1`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this: `result, created = TestVersion.objects.get_or_create(test=test)` 
`get_or_create` returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

Look here for a reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: `count` is name of field, not method